# How to separate two columns into array using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell

This is the sample data set I am using currently:

```
ID       Name     command     xxx   xxxxx    xxxxx   xxxx   xxxxx
5474558  abcd     run         xxx   xxxxx    xxxxx   xxxx   xxxxx
8487848  xyze     bash        xxx   xxxxx    xxxxx   xxxx   xxxxx
```

distance between ID and Name 8 spaces.

I need ID and Name in to two separate array.

sample output I need is:

```
id=[5474558,8487848]
name=[abcd,xyze]
```

Using shell script how can I do this?

Comment: Post what you've tried and what error you see please.

Comment: You added expected output but didn't show the script you've tried?

Comment: why peoples down vote???

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands It will print the IDS and Names this just an hint.

For ID's

```
awk '{if (NR !=1 ) printf $1}' data.txt
```

For Name's

```
awk '{if (NR !=1 ) printf $2}' data.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

A solution in perl :

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, '<', "file.txt" or die "couldn't open file : $!";

while( <$fh> ) {
    next if $. == 1;
    chomp;
    my @columns = split /\s+/, $_;
    push (my @ids, $columns[0]);
    push (my @names, $columns[1]);
}
```